# A catalyst catalyses a spontaneous reaction but does not catalyse a non-spontaneous reaction. Why?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was just studying chemical kinetics and it was written in my textbook that

> "A catalyst catalyses spontaneous reaction but does not catalyse a non-spontaneous reaction".

But why? Why does a catalyst not catalyse a non-spontaneous reaction. There is literally no explanation in my textbook as to why this is true. Please explain. I am really confused. Would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Actually, I got this in my physics textbook. The chapter was "Chemical Kinetics".